# Reading lyrics information from a .kar file in java

Tags: java, file

I want to develop a karaoke player in Java that works with kar files. I got it to play the song, but I coundn't make it read the lyric information from the file. I've searched a lot, but I coundn't find any clue about how kar files work.

How can I do it? I appreciate some example.
Thanks.

Comment: If you guys want an example of kar file, here it is: http://p.download.uol.com.br/cante/kar/Beatles_-_Dont_let_me_down.kar

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a Java library for that so you'll have to write it on your own code.

First, you need to know the inner structure of a .kar file. Since these files are so small, they're probably some kind of text files. Try opening one of them with your text editor and see what it looks like. Then you'll know how to process it.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't find any kar file structure documentation. I've already tried to open it with a text editor but most part of the information isn't readable.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies as I don't have a definitive answer for you. I have seen several discussions about this but no real solid solutions. Here are a couple links to others' discussions on the topic. It seems to be a much more complicated task than one might imagine, as it is an uncommonly used file type. From what I know, it consists of MIDI data, albeit with slightly different meta data.

[Reading lyrics information from a .kar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860341/reading-lyrics-information-from-a-kar-file)

[How to read MIDI file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845825/how-to-read-midi-file-in-c?rq=1)

Can you open the .kar file in a text editor? What does it give you?

Comment: I've already seen the first topic and the second one isn't exactly what I want, but thanks.
I can open the kar file in a text editor, but I can only read the lyric which is fragmented along the text. I also need the timing information in order to make the karaoke player.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find is this:

> "KAR"
>
> Origin: The Company Tune 1000 A file kar (kar) is in fact, a midi
>   file, but whose words are standardized in events meta of the type
>   TEXT. The texts starting with @ are additional indications compared to
>   the words. Example:
>
> @L specifies the language of the words
>   @I any additional information
>   @T information of title
>   @KMIDI KARAOKE SPINS information of copyright
>   and type of file
>
> Several lines of titles and information can be present. KaraWin
>   extracts information from titles to post them. The text even has a
>   very simple format to him: \ indicates a page break, /a return
>   indicates has the line

[Source.](http://www.karawin.fr/defenst.php)

Besides that, according to [Wikipedia, XBMC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBMC) is an open source program that supports kar files. Since it's an open source project, you can [download its code](http://xbmc.org/download/). If you are really interested, you can try searching among its 10k+ files (in C, not Java), how they do it. Maybe you can ask them or in their [forum](http://forum.xbmc.org/) for a little bit of guidance.

You can also try in [this yahoo group](http://launch.groups.yahoo.com/group/softkaraoke/) about karaoke software.

Comment: I've already read this text. I'll try to do what you said. Maybe it can be useful, thanks.